# MYSQL: Dynamic columns in mysql --> first, last name to full name:

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic

I was wondering if you have two columns for lets say

```
first name. 
last name.
```

what you store in the database.

Can you create a 'dynamic' column 'fullname' in the database that automatically creates the name out of the first and last name?

```
firstname   |lastname   |fullname (this goes automatically)
-----------------------------------------
foo         |bar        |foo bar
```

Comment: why do you want to store this in the database?  You can easily create this via a `select` query.

Comment: i understand but then you keep writing select statements.

Comment: Then don't keep writing the same sql more than once. Wrap it in a function and call that function instead.

Comment: well then you need to do that for each join, different statements ect, you do and would require to go trough all the code again to change the sql with the function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to select the full name, you can do just that:

```
 select concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullname from users
```

If you actually want a column (i.e. be able to perform updates against it), then it's not possible, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as firstlast FROM users
```

Answer (score 0):

This one also makes sure that no empty spaces are added:

```
SELECT IF(ISNULL(firstname), lastname, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)) AS fullname FROM users
```